# filtering $http json data with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have read through numerous questions here already, but something just isnt clicking with me and understanding this issue i have.

the js code:

```
    app.controller('example_ctrl',['$scope','$http', function($scope, 
    $http){
    $http.get('api_call_here').then(function successCallBack(response){
    $scope.response = response;
    });
```

Json format of api:

```
    {
      "categoryOne": {
        "1": {
          "title": "someData1",
          "description": "This is number One"
        },
        "2": {
          "title": "moreData1",
          "description": "I am not a number, I'm a free man!"
        }
      }
    }
```

Now because this hasnt been returned in an array, I get an error whenever I try to filter it. As an example:

```
    <div ng-repeat="(category, object) in response.data">
       <div ng-repeat="item in object">
         <p>{{item.title}}</p>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Now if i try to put an ng-model on a search input, and tie that to the ng-repeat with a |filter:ng-model name, I get an error.

What I basically WANT to do, is when you type text into the search field, have it return only the title/descriptions that contain that text.

Comment: have you checked the output header from your api is set to application/json? it would not return real json if it is only a string

Comment: It returns an object when i console.log result.

Comment: You have to map the items to arrays since filter doesn't work on object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform the list of object in each category to array:

```js
app.controller('example_ctrl',['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('api_call_here').then(function(response) {    
        Object.keys(response.data).forEach(function(category) {
        response.data[category] = Object.values(response.data[category]); // Transfom list of objects in each category to array
    });
    console.log("transformed: ", response);
    $scope.response = response; 
});
```

Comment: Note you could also do the filtering in controller instead of added overhead in view